# Boto-like library for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Boto provides a simple way to upload a file to Amazon S3:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, settings.AWS_SECRET_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket) # my 'folder'
key = bucket.new_key(s3_filename) # my 'filename'
key.set_contents_from_filename('myfile.txt')
```

Is there an equivalent way to do the same for Google Cloud Storage with python? All the examples I've seen have involved 50+ lines of code to do a 'simple' operation, like upload a local file.

How could this be done (from the CLI)?

Comment: You're aware you can use boto to talk to GCS too? The examples here look pretty similar to your code: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For program use via Python, the boto library and gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin let you use essentially the same code for interacting with GCS, as you can use for S3 (or presumably other cloud storage services with the right plugins).

See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary for instructions on how to download and install the library and plugin, and several short example snippets of Python code to perform various operations.  Other detailed instructions are at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#boto .

CLI usage is even simpler; once you've installed and authenticated `gsutil`, for example, a typical "upload a bunch of files" CLI command is

```
$ gsutil cp *.txt gs://my_bucket
```

(using `$` to mean "the shell prompt":-).